# Can't make a DISTINCT search in an Apache Solr View

Tags: views, search

I have a set up Apache Solr on my Drupal 7 site.  I have an [apache solr view](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views).  I would like to created distinct results based off an indexed field called 'Part Number'; however, the solr view ui doesn't provide a 'DISTINCT' option.  Does anyone know of a good workaround for this?

Comment: Could you share just a little bit about your entity structure?  I have the same issue using Search API Views against a Solr index where I am indexing child nodes in a parent:child relationship.  I want to show only resultant parent nodes (and not have them repeated for every matching child).

Comment: I created a new feature request on the Apache Solr View project queue https://drupal.org/node/2139635.  I hope I'm not off the mark here - these seems like a pretty common issue that could have a simple solution.